# How to make flags more informative?

Tags: discussion, flagging

A few hours ago, I flagged [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/597883/360892) answer as “In need of moderator intervention”. What I should have done and what I want it to do was flag it as “not an answer”. Plus, I knew there was a chance this flag will get declined. And understandably it did.

*So why did I do it?*

This answer provides information to “speed up the process” of executing the other answers. To be clear, I consider the “tip” to be utterly superfluous. But still, at that moment, I thought that it should be a comment in an answer. So instead of flagging it as “not an answer” I flagged it as “In need of moderator intervention” with this side note.

> This doesn't answer the question. It should be a comment in one of the already posted answers.

**The only reason I did this, is because I had no other way of telling the moderator that this post should be converted in to a comment of an answer. I imagine it’s hard to see that through the review queue.**

I remember reading a [post](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5357/360892) by Jeff Schaller saying

> The custom flag “in need of moderator intervention” should only be used when one of the other flag categories can’t be used.

so I was not surprised to see

> declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see What is Flagging?

**Question:** What should I do when dealing with that kind of situations? What's the best way to inform the moderator of the rational behind the flag?

*(Perhaps a side note functionality would come in handy, when dealing with situations like this.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that Jeff Schaller guy! :)

I happened to decline that flag, with the thinking "if it's not an Answer, flag it as such", so we're on the same page.

If you've cast a flag that you want to change or retract, you can [retract your flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281010/307535) by clicking on the same 'flag' link again. If you then cast a "not an answer flag", it would go to the LQP queue, where user-moderators can choose what to do with it. If an elected moderator sees it before it's deleted, they *could* choose to convert the answer to a comment if they think there's enough value in it.

In this particular case, it seems to me that the OP is already aware of the ability to have `nmcli` list the connections with their UUIDS and names, so I would recommend deleting that answer altogether.

If you think something should really be a comment, consider leaving that comment yourself -- you could pick and choose the most valuable parts of the "answer" and use those as a comment; that answer could then be flagged appropriately.  I would encourage you (and everyone) to consider whether your comment should be an edit to the post or not.

Comment: I had no idea, I could retract a flag. Good to know.